# Delete all comments in a C program

Tags: beginner, c, parsing

I am new to C. And I just want to know if my code is horrible or not. I tried to make program to delete all comments in C program. It's from "The C Programming Language Second Edition" book, Exercise 1-23.

Here is my solution :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXCHAR 1000
int c = 0;
int d = 0;
int newFileText[MAXCHAR];
int longDisable = 0;
int shortDisable = 0;
int i = 0;

//Function declarations
void printArray(int a[], int b);

void myputchar(int a[], int c);

int main(void) {
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (i > MAXCHAR)i = 0;
        if (c == '/') {
            d = getchar();
            if (d == '/') shortDisable = 1;
            else if (d == '*') longDisable = 1;
        } else if (c == '*') {
            d = getchar();
            if (d == '/') {
                c = getchar();
                if (!(c > 0)) {
                    break;
                }
                longDisable = 0;
            }
        } else if (c == '\n') {
            shortDisable = 0;
        }
        if (shortDisable || longDisable);
        else {
            myputchar(newFileText, c);
            i++;
        }
        /*printf("\nShort disable: %d", shortDisable);
        printf("\nLong disable: %d", longDisable);*/
    }
    printArray(newFileText, i);
    return 0;
}

void printArray(int theArray[], int lengthSoFar) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lengthSoFar; i++) {
        printf("%c", theArray[i]);
    }
}

void myputchar(int a[], int c) {
    int i = 0;
    while (a[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
    }
    a[i] = c;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this other code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/115073/97584) which tried to solve the same exercise. Maybe you can learn something from that question and it's answers, too.

Comment: Its far too complicated than it should be i think.There is more simpler answer.Answered by @200_success

Comment: But ivan's solution accounts for string literals correctly, so there is something to be learned from it.

Comment: I'm just too beginner to C, to understand his code.I had a look.But nothing seems understandable for me :)

Comment: Well ^that being said, you have to start learning new things. It's useful. Enjoy your trip in C-world !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Bugs

When processing an expression like `10/2` or `10*2`, the `2` gets discarded from the output.

It looks like you attempted to implement a circular buffer for the output, but it actually fails miserably if the output exceeds 1000 bytes.  One problem is performance: `myputchar()` performs a linear scan of the buffer to find the end of the string, where it can write the next character.  A second problem is buffer overflow: `myputchar()` makes no attempt to ensure that the location where it stores the next character lies within the buffer.  The third problem is that when you do `if (i > MAXCHAR)i = 0`, you haven't made any attempt to print the buffer contents before trying to reuse the buffer.

### C grammar

In C, a `/*` or `//` that appears within a `"string literal"` should be treated literally.  It should not be interpreted as a start-of-comment marker.

Furthermore, within a `//`-style comment, any `/*` or `*/` needs to be disregarded.  Similarly, within a `/* */`-style comment, any `//` should be disregarded.  That is, the correct output for the following C99 program…

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> int main() {
>     puts("First " /* asdf // */ "example"
>     );
>     puts("Second " // /*
>          "example"
>          // */
>     );
>     puts("Third " /* "/" */ "example");
> }
> ```

… should be

> ```
> First example
> Second example
> Third example
> ```

(I also got this wrong in Rev 1 of this answer.  I've corrected the bug, but this illustrates a point that C requires a stateful parser.)

### Organization

The variables `c`, `d`, `newFileText`, `longDisable`, `shortDisable`, and `i` are global; they should all be local to the `main` function.

It is customary to put the `main` function last, so that you don't need to declare the functions it uses.

### Input / output

You read one character at a time with `getchar()`, but you attempt to print the output in chunks of up to 1000 characters.  Writing in chunks could be more efficient than writing a character at a time, but it is certainly more difficult to implement correctly.  However, after you go through the effort of accumulating the chunks, you then proceed to print the buffer one character at a time using `printf("%c", theArray[i])`, which negates any performance advantage you could have gained.

Therefore, you would have been better off printing the output one character at a time to begin with, without any attempt at buffering.  To do so, you could use `putchar(…)`, which is simpler than `printf("%c", …)`.

If you did want to efficiently write a chunk of bytes at a time, you could use the `write()` function instead of the loop in `printArray()`.

### Suggested solution

This solution addresses the more serious logic bugs, without attempting to handle string literals correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, d;
    int longDisable = 0, shortDisable = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        switch (c) {
          case '/':
          case '*':
            d = getchar();
            if (!longDisable && c == '/' && d == '/') {
                shortDisable = 1;
            } else if (!shortDisable && c == '/' && d == '*') {
                longDisable = 1;
            } else if (!shortDisable && c == '*' && d == '/') {
                longDisable = 0;
            } else if (!(shortDisable || longDisable)) {
                putchar(c);
                if (d != EOF) putchar(d);
            }
            break;

          case '\n':
            shortDisable = 0;
            /* fall through... */
          default:
            if (!(shortDisable || longDisable)) {
                putchar(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the lesson :) And some people told me that `(char c=getchar())!=EOF` is bad to do.They said i should do int c instead of char c.

Comment: Actually, you're right. Technically, it should be `int c, d`.

Comment: And there is one part that i dont understand very well.I am not really familiar with switch statement so i might be wrong.You wrote `if (c=='/' && d=='/')`.Isnt c anyways equal to `'*'` there ?? Because its in case `'*'` ??

Comment: No.  The way `switch` works, if `c` is either `'/'` or `'*'`, the code starting with `d = getchar()` will be executed.

Comment: Oh,okay i understand now.Thank you for helping me out.This code looks much better than mine.Its far too simpler.Nice lesson :)